# Changing Web application's context-param and init-param on the fly

Tags: tomcat, web.xml, param, reloadable

As I remember one can change a value of  in a web.xml within a Web application on the fly without restarting a Web Server if “reloadable=true” is specified.  However,    I cannot find documentation confirming this statement particularly for Tomcat.

See example of context-param:

```
<context-param>  
  <description>This is a context parameter example</description>  
  <param-name>ContextParam</param-name>  
  <param-value>ContextParam value</param-value>  
</context-param>
```

The same question is about init-param, for example:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>LoginServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>jdbcDriver</param-name>
    <param-value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>
```